# How do I prevent HTMLHelper::link() from adding keywords to the URL path? (CakePHP 2.5)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5, cakephp-2.x

I have a common layout with a button for opening a specific page :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('My cart', array('controller' => 'shop', 'action' => 'cart'), array('escape' => false)) ?>
```

This link will redirect to a page `/shop/cart` . But if I'm in a page using another controller I have a problem. Example : I'm on a page depending on UsersController, my URL is : `customer/` and now if I'm clicking on 'My Cart' link, URL is : `customer/shop/cart` which is an error.

How can I clear my URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably set *customer* as a routing prefix in /Config/core.php:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('customer'));
```

and you are linking to /shop/cart from within an action that starts with *customer_*.

This is the default behavior.

To remove the prefix, rewrite the link as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('My cart', array('controller' => 'shop', 'action' => 'cart','customer'=>false), array('escape' => false)) ?>
```

More on [Prefix Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing).